# Continuous Random Variable, PDF

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with pdf:
$f_\mu(x)=  1/2\mu(x/2)^{(1/(\mu-1))}$,     for  $0\leq x\leq 2$ and zero otherwise with $\mu>0$

How do I express the expected value $E(X)$ and variance $Var(X)$? The integral in this case will be very ugly...

Comment: Welcome to math SE. Have a look at [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for your mathematical expressions.

Comment: Ugly but solvable with pen and paper. Just needs a bit of patience. Yes you can!

Comment: Not that ugly if you know how to solve $\int x^\alpha dx$.

Comment: what does the subscript mu denote?